# Can't get Office 2010 to run under Wine

Tags: 12.10, wine, microsoft-office

I can't get Microsoft Office 2010 Home and Student to install on Ubuntu 12.10 under the latest version of Wine. I've tried both the 32- and 64 bit installers but they both fail about two thirds of the way into the installation.

How can I install Office 2010 using Wine?

Comment: We can not unless you provide details on why it does not install.

Comment: [Wine AppDB Entry for the 64bit installer](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18487) | [Wine AppDB Entry for 32bit Installer](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336)  ||  Generally, Office 2010 isn't wine-friendly.  You will need to attach the errors you're seeing here, otherwise we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

i finally make working office 2010 and 2013 boths versions of 32 bits, 64 bits i don't know why no works, but i explain the two ways of install both. first you need the installers of office 2010 professional plus. later follow the steps, dependences and architecture of 32 bits.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

remove all wine do you have

```
sudo apt remove wine*
```

later install from repositories

```
wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
wine --version
sudo apt install winetricks
```

later of this installation you need prepare for install office

first setup with

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wineoffice2010 winetricks dotnet20 msxml6 corefonts
```

this install gecko and mono, you need install them, later install office with the setup

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wineoffice2010 wine Download/office/setup.exe
```

and finally test word, excel and others, for me working in ubuntu 18.04 and working good

Answer (score -1):

Here is a video of someone who has Office 2010 installed on Ubuntu 10.10.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcPpn_Ugs2o
In the description, he writes:

> Ubuntu 10.10 PL, WINE 1.3.17, MS Office 2010 PL
>
> Winetricks: dotnet2, msxml6, Visual C++ 2005.
>
> Original urlmon.dll (ie6 version - from Google, ie7 version will not
>   work ), Original msvcr90.dll (from Google)

Otherwise, you'll find even a tutorial here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336

Comment: You should not be posting suggestions which refer only to Ubuntu 10.10.  10.10 is EOL.

Comment: I think, however, it requires the same packages. (dotnet2, msxml6, Visual C++ 2005 ...)

Comment: Excuse me everyone, not meaning to be rude but I explicitly stated Ubuntu **12.10** not 10.10